Can I change the hub of DT Swiss Gravel LN to add clicking sound?
I'm recently got a Canyon Grizl 6 which has DT Swiss Gravel LN wheelset. I was looking forward for the clicking sound from the wheels when coasting however the wheelset is completely silent when coasting.
I love the clicking sound and definitely want to have it, the question is how. From this reddit thread it seems that I have pawl freehub and not the ratchet based one. Could I change the hub in the rear wheel to get the sound? My previous bike Merida Silex 400 had amazing clicking sound using rear hub Shimano "HB-TC500-HM" which seems to cost around 50 euro. Is it feasible to install it to DT Swiss Gravel LN? How difficult would it be (I have very basic bicycle repair skills)?
If it's too difficult and I buy another rear wheel is it ok to have rear wheel from another brand and front wheel DT Swiss?

How about taping a piece of cardboard to frame so that it buzzes against the spokes?

When looking for the possibility of removing a "silencer" on DT Swiss hubs (some ratchet-hubs from other brands have a rubber part that you can remove if you want a noisy hub), I found the following tutorial from DT Swiss, that explains a conversion in the other direction (pawl to ratchet):



So it looks it's possible to do on some hubs. I would however recommend to contact Canyon or DT Swiss for the parts references, as the wheelsets supplied by Canyon don't always match the ones that are retailed separately. The conversion has a cost however, and it must be compared against buying a new equivalent wheel.
On running different wheels, no problem at all, wheels/frame interfaces are very standard.
Instead of replacing one wheel, a common practice with gravel bikes (especially the ones with double chainrings) is to have two wheelsets: one fitted with gravel tires, and the other one fitted with road tires - with rotors and cassette, so that the swap is easy.
Just a note however, upgrading wheels does a lot in terms of how a bike "feels", and given your bike has entry-level wheels (I do not mean bad, they come from a very reputable brand, just that there are better options), you won't need to spend a lot to have a noticeable difference.

When you say "one fitted with gravel tires, and the other one fitted with road tires - with rotors and cassette, so that the swap is easy." you mean that the original rotor and casette stay just the wheels are swapped right?

@Yos I meant that the two pair of wheels should be fully equipped, to swap them easily and avoid having to swap more than the wheels.  Leaving the original rotors and cassette on the original wheels is indeed easier.

I have one more question: why isn’t my wheel makong sound at all, because it’s pawl based? Because I saw videos where pawl based wheels make loud sound as well.

@Yos Noise depends on the kind of pawl/ratchet, and the grease (thin grease is noisiest), but it's hard to know just by looking at the specs what noise you'll have. There are quiet and noisy hubs of both kinds (and it depends on the model as well), so hard to draw rules. Ratchet hubs allow more freedom in the kind of noise they produce though (you can change the number of engagement points and the grease). But to be honest, I'm looking in the other direction: how to have the silent ones, so I didn't really search into the different of noise you can have.

Probably not possible to swap the freehub from another brand. Hub parts are proprietary and typically not interchangeable. Pawls count, size and shape are likely different, and if not, would be just as silent as it is the design that makes them noisy or silent.
Swapping the wheel with one from another brand, that suits your needs better, is not a problem.
